# How do I connect to Twitter via TwitterVB?

Tags: c#, twitter

I am trying to connect to twitter via TwitterVB and the following code does not work(note: removed the consumerKey and consumerKeySecret for privacy issues). When I run the following code it pops up a web page(Attached). What am I doing wrong?

Code:
        string consumerKey = "";
        string consumerKeySecret = "";

```
    TwitterVB2.TwitterAPI tw = new TwitterVB2.TwitterAPI();
    if (Request["oauth_token"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect(tw.GetAuthorizationLink(consumerKey, consumerKeySecret));
        Debug.WriteLine(tw.OAuth_Token);
        Debug.WriteLine(tw.OAuth_TokenSecret);
    }
    else
    {
        tw.GetAccessTokens(consumerKey, consumerKeySecret, Request["oauth_token"], Request["oauth_verifier"]);
        Debug.WriteLine(tw.OAuth_Token);
        Debug.WriteLine(tw.OAuth_TokenSecret);
    }
```

Screenshot: http://picasaweb.google.com/110153104476017462305/Screenshots#5521379134576882050

Comment: And what do you expect to get? That is how OAuth works. ps: you can attach images right here with "Image" button

Comment: I want to be able to automate the whole process i.e. without an authetication page popping up. Instead, I would rather the page not popping up and I being able to specify the user name/password in a later session. I just want to able to log into to twitter and get feeds and then exit. Is that another process independant of OAuth?

Comment: OAuth implies you're doing authentication just once. But after you've got `key` and `secret` - you can store them and use infinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: you need to get `key` and `secret` to have access to twitter account. And that could be done **only** with that form on the screenshot. But that should be done just **once**. So - give the permission and store `key + secret` somewhere.

And here are some useful links for you:

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth
http://hueniverse.com/oauth/
http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of TwitterVB. :)

Your best bet is to read the web tutorial at the following link:

http://twittervb.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OAuth%20Web%20Tutorial&referringTitle=OAuth

It spells it out pretty clearly.  Third-party applications may no longer sign in to Twitter using username and password; you have to store the OAuth tokens.